# How to E2E test a REST API that has some websocket endpoints?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, robotframework, cypress, e2e-testing

I am looking to automate testing for an REST API that has some websocket endpoints.
The API has a feel similar to an application that can add/list serially connected sensors (typical REST CRUD) and then allow for the direct connection to them (websocket). There is currently no frontend and I would like to perform E2E and integration tests with real and mocked hardware.

Minimally, the solution would:

- run via an agent on a testbed I or it created
- do the typical CRUD tests (add sensor, edit sensor, etc.)
- open a websocket connection (IE: '/websock?sensorID=10') and then have the typical expect script test behavior (`wait for`,`read`,`write`, `assert`). An Echo websocket would be an ideal first test.

The ideal solution would have this and:

- incorporate the typical browser focused testing in the future
- grab data from additional servers to verify behavior (IE: after a REST `PUT`, query the SQL database directly to verify)
- integrate into the typical JIRA DevOps flow

I have looked at Selenium and Cypress, but it is not clear if or how they can satisfy these requirements as the documentation is almost entirely browser focused.

Comment: What is actually your question? They way at least I read it is "propose a sample framework architecture for websocket testing" - which is very broad, and generic. And, selenium/cypress are frameworks for driving a web browser, they'll hardly provide direct websocket capabilities. Look into a python library that gives you that - for example https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, and build a solution on top of it.

Comment: @TodorMinakov the main question is what modern test framework can handle API and streaming data directly. Right now it looks like Cypress can though it prefers just working via the browser.